# Update a linked table(In access 2003) through Excel VBA

Tags: database, excel, vba, sharepoint

I have some data in Excel that needs to be updated into a linked table in MS access. The link table connects to a sharepoint site. The code I have so far only works with regular table. rs.Open returns unspecified error in this case.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
On Error GoTo ExceptionHandle
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset

' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
"Data Source=D:\.....\db1.mdb;"


' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'ERROR 
 rs.Open "LinkedTableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Range("B2").Activate  ' row 1 contains column headings

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    s_title = ActiveCell.Offset.Value
    s_start_time = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    s_end_time = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    rs.Filter = "Title ='" & s_title & "'"
                If rs.EOF Then
                     Debug.Print "No existing record - adding new..."
                     rs.Filter = ""
                     rs.AddNew
                Else
                     Debug.Print "Existing record found..."
                End If

    rs("Title").Value = s_title
    rs("Start Time").Value = s_start_time
    rs("End Time").Value = s_end_time

    rs.Update
    Debug.Print "...record update complete."

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate  ' next cell down
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

ExitProcedure:
  MsgBox "Update success"
  Exit Sub

ExceptionHandle:
  MsgBox "Error:" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: You say it won't give you an error number for the issue?  It could be many things, what happens when you change that line like this: `rs.Open "Select * from LinkedTableName", cn`

Comment: The full error message is: "Error:-2147467259: Unspecified error". I tried using your line, it returns the same error message

Comment: I hate the generic errors ADO provides... well can you open the table in the Access database and view the data without issue?  Does it require a password?  Have you tried to use a DAO recordset?  `Set cn = DAO.OpenDatabase("d:\db1.mdb")  Set rs = cn.OpenRecordset("Select * from LinkedTable")`

Comment: I can view and make modifications on the link table from MS access. However, when I try to use DAO method, cn.OpenRecordset() return an error 3033 saying I don't have the necessary permission to use "select * from linkTableName" object. Is it possible to use ADO method?

Comment: Yeah, ADO is the preferred way, I was just trying to determine if it's a permission issue, as there's nothing inherently wrong with the original code itself. Do you have full control of the folder the database is in?

Comment: The source of the link table is from a SharePoint site. Their DB information is unknown. And yes, I do have full control over the access DB folder. What I think is that since I'm able to modify values inside the link table from Access, I should be able to it using excel.

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?  You may want to test the new provider with your ado, `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` Check out [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/54e32c6a-64bd-41f0-b24b-b6d6bf2aa9b6/trouble-inserting-into-sharepoint-access-db-with-adodb-connection?forum=accessdev)

Comment: I'm using Access 2003. OLEDB.12.0 Returns error "Could not find installable ISAM." It looks like MS disabled it for office 2003 sp2. [Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/62ee4978-ca29-48d3-9367-6dd4ab639d2d/could-not-find-installable-isam)

Comment: All else fails, I would setup an ODBC - make sure you can connect to that, believe it has a "Test" button.  Afterwards, use the ODBC in your ADO connection string.  This doesn't answer your original question, but may help in troubleshooting.